# Выполнить код, если в базе появилась новая запись

Tags: php, mysql

Необходимо выполнить код на php, если в базе данных mysql появилась новая запись. Гуглил по делу ничего нет. Код представляет из себя всплывающее уведомление.Есть пример всплывающего уведомления codepen.io/anon/pen/hCwyv. Подскажите какими средствами мне сделать проверку появления новой записи в бд.

Comment: Как вы понимаете что в базе `появилась новая строка`?

Comment: где выполнить? на php? тогда почему ajax? или на странице сайта? для ajax можно и [jquery](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) использовать, там ничего сложного; и что именно у вас вызвало трудности? лучше не просить код (его могут и не дать), а показать что вы делали и что вызвало проблему

Comment: *Знаю, что здесь может помочь ajax, но как с ним работать не знаю* - может быть вначале стоит разобраться как работает ajax ?

Comment: а *срач* здесь из за формулировки вашего вопроса. сформулируйте конкретно что не получается и глядишь ответ будет, и минусы уйдут. Что за база, как она туда попадает ну и т.п.

Comment: @pavel,  а вот не насрешь в коментах человек и не поймет что не прав. Завтра такой же вопрос задаст. А так, может есть шанс :)

Comment: По моему мнению, Вам подойдет либо `socket`, либо `ajax`. Судя по вопросу, Вы новичок, так что и то и другое по-перву сложно. Однако по `ajax` больше информации, да и проще он. Вобщем, как Вам советовал Alex, почитайте про `ajax`, попробуйте, и, уже сделав несколько самостоятельных попыток, спрашивайте. Тогда Вам тут точно помогут и без *срача* в комментах... А этот вопрос я бы на Вашем месте удалил....

Comment: Ну, смысл-то вопроса понятен. Бежит скрипт, тем временем другой процесс модифицирует базу, как получить нотификацию. Плюс как доставить клиенту эту нотификацию. За что заминусовали?

Answer (score 0):

Для этого давным давно была сделана технология Ajax. Для того чтобы Вам было проще разобраться, подскажу, что это можно проверить по установленному же Вами флагу. Удачи.